# Is there any way to save pointer of any function in the struct?

Tags: pointers, rust, struct, func

I've been wondering is there any way to get pointer of function with unspecified arguments and output types (unspecification of output type isn't as necessary as arguments). For example, in C++ when you are spawning new thread you pass function pointer without any specification.

As I see it can solved with trait that would represent `fn` in the same way as `std::marker::Tuple` represents `Tuple` object.

Example:

```
struct Cont <F: FN_TRAIT> {
    func: F,
}

impl<F: FN_TRAIT> Cont <F> {
    fn new(func: F) -> Self {
        Self { func: func }
    }

    fn start(&self, args: dyn std::marker::Tuple) {
        self.func.call(args);
    }
}

fn temp(a: i32, b: i32) {
    println!("{}", a + b);
}

fn main() {
    let a = Cont::new(temp);
    a.start((0,1));
}
```

I tried to find the way to represent `fn` with trait in the struct and then call it with std::marker::Tuple as arguments.

Comment: What would you like to do with the stored pointer? Since you don't know what kind of arguments it takes, you won't be able to call it. In most cases, you can store a `Fn()` instead, and if you need to pass arguments to the function you pass in a closure like `move || foo(x, y, z)`.

Comment: Note that `Tuple` is a lang-item (i.e. it's built into the compiler). It also doesn't have any behaviours, so knowing that a type implements `Tuple` doesn't allow you to do anything at all with it. The `Tuple` trait is only useful for other things built into the compiler, e.g. for constraining the `Args` parameter of the `Fn` trait.

Comment: The whole point was to rely on Rust's compiler. Rust's Fn already can get any function, and call it with any tuple passed `std::ops::Fn::call(&|name_of_function|, |name_of_tuple|);` and the compiler itself recognizes that we'he passed function and checks if passed tuple meets the needs of function.

Comment: Move closure doesn't work in my case, because the whole point is to create automatically the wrap for function and its arguments and to don't do it manually in the closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with generics mostly the same as C++ does it:

```
struct Cont<Args, F> {
    args: Args,
    fun: F,
}

impl<Args, F> Cont<Args, F> {
    fn new (fun: F, args: Args) -> Self {
        Cont { args, fun, }
    }
}

impl<A, R, F: FnOnce (A) -> R> Cont<(A,), F> {
    fn call (self) -> R {
        (self.fun) (self.args.0)
    }
}

impl<A0, A1, R, F: FnOnce (A0, A1) -> R> Cont<(A0, A1), F> {
    fn call (self) -> R {
        (self.fun) (self.args.0, self.args.1)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c1 = Cont::new (|x| 2*x, (0,));
    let c2 = Cont::new (|x, y| x+y, (2, 3));
    println!("{} {}", c1.call(), c2.call());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=aeacc21854d721855088ffb0265f1a5f)

Except that you need to add an implementation for each possible number of arguments (this can probably be simplified with a macro).

Comment: What's the advantage of using this over closures without argument?